# What is Insight for?

Tags: bloodborne

In Bloodborne I currently have 10 Insight, and about 3 or 4 Madman's Knowledge, which I can convert to Insight.

From what I've read, the higher Insight you have, the harder the game becomes; is that right?

What's the flip-side of Insight? I believe you can sell it for something?

Related: [Does increasing your Insight unlock new items to buy from the Insight Bath Messenger?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212570/does-increasing-your-insight-unlock-new-items-to-buy-from-the-insight-bath-messe)

Comment: All I know so far is that you use it to summon other player's. I'm sure there's more.

Comment: @Reafexus I just noticed there's a 2nd Bath Messenger in the Hunter's Dream that you can buy stuff from with Insight. Nothing good to get from it so far for me though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Insight is an additional currency besides Blood Echoes and you will mostly gain it by seeing and defeating bosses, or by playing online. Helping another player to defeat a boss or killing them by invasion both give you one insight. You can also increase it by using your "Madman's Knowledge".

Once you have 10 insight, another messenger store will open in the Hunter's Dream where you can spend your insight. More items will become available there as you progress in the game. For example, I could buy Father Gascoigne's clothing there after I beat him. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe killing bosses makes new items available. After killing a few bosses, I can buy materials like Bloodstone shards and a few consumables like Fire Paper. Keep in mind that the store closes again if your insight drops below 10.

Besides spending it on items, you can use insight to ring the Beckoning Bell, which enables other players, who rung a Small Resonant Bell, to join your game for a round of jolly co-operation. By spending one insight, you will invite other players into your game until you die, use the Silencing Blank or return to the Hunter's Dream.

The downside of gaining insight is, that enemy behaviour will change, which makes them more difficult to fight. Most of this is still unexplored, but it seems that the changes occur at 15 insight. One I noticed for example is an enemy in front of the Grand Cathedral, which gains a ranged magic attack. I found a video of it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cKEM7NuyQw).

Gaining insight also makes you [more vulnerable to frenzy inflicting attacks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213438/how-much-does-insight-affect-your-frenzy-resistance).

Most of the effects of insight are still unknown, so there may be a lot more effects than we know of yet. For example, a few enemies stopped spawning and some were found in different places in my game, but I don't know if that was caused by gaining insight or because the game world changes as you kill more bosses.

Comment: That's a good video to demonstrate the difficulty increase, nice find - thanks!

Comment: According to Super Bunnyhop, Insight also makes you more vulnerable to Frenzy. He mentions this and a couple of other Insight-related effenct in his latest video https://youtu.be/voMAx-lKfIw

Comment: @DJPirtu Thanks for the hint. I added a link to a question about the affect on frenzy resistance. It's a very interesting video as well.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this wiki link](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Insight). You can acquire it in many ways and its used mostly to summon players to your world for co-op. Also acquiring certain amounts of Insight will unlock certain effects/events in the game world.