# How much does Insight affect your Frenzy resistance?

Tags: bloodborne

Supposedly the more Insight you have the lower your frenzy resistance is. If it does, what is the formula to determine how much lower your Frenzy resistance will be given X amount of Insight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So there are three levels of Frenzy Resistance (and possibly a 4th starting at or around 60 Insight.)

0 - 15  - No affect (100 Frenzy in my case)
16 - 30 - Each point of Insight is about -2.66 Frenzy RES
30+     - Each point of insight is about -1.3 Frenzy RES

- 0 Insight - 100 Frenzy RES
- 15 Insight - 100 Frenzy RES
- 16 Insight - 97 Frenzy RES
- 30 Insight - 60 Frenzy RES
- 40 Insight - 46 Frenzy RES
- 60 Insight - 20 Frenzy RES
- 99 Insight - 10 Frenzy RES